# Convert RAW images to JPEG

Tags: automation, photography, media-converter, jpg, raw

Please recommend software to convert over 250 RAW images (taken via a Canon DSLR) to JPEG format.

Requirements:

1. Windows compatible (Command line or GUI is fine)
2. Gratis
3. Preserves EXIF information during the conversion
4. Does not require manual interaction for each file

Preference:

1. Allow me to specify the amount of JPEG compression

Comment: [Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/)?

Comment: XNView? It reads RAW, not sure about that specific model

Comment: Gimp (https://www.gimp.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

Any RAW processing tool can do it

The most common ones on Windows are [darktable](https://www.darktable.org/) and [rawtherapee](http://rawtherapee.com/)

Each camera manufacturer also have their own tools for editing their cameras' raw files, like Canon's [Digital Photo Professional](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/software/digital-photo-professional.aspx?os=WINDOWS%2010%20(64-bit)&language=EN)

- [Is there good free software for editing Canon RAW files?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5736/25588)
- [How do popular free RAW editor/converter compare to each other on Windows?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1717/25588)